# Using CSV to click specific checkboxes using python selenium webdriver

Tags: python, csv, selenium, checkbox

I am still fairly new to the selenium webdriver scene and need some help.  I am trying to use a csv file and the value in a specific column to click a specific checkbox on a page using python.
Here are the options for the checkboxes:

```
<input id="GroupsElected_0" name="GroupsElected" type="checkbox" value="ALL">
<input id="GroupsElected_1" name="GroupsElected" type="checkbox" value="newtest">
<input id="GroupsElected_2" name="GroupsElected" type="checkbox" value="test">
```

I can make it click the checkbox if I give it the actual value:

```
group=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='checkbox'][value='ALL']").click()
```

What I want to do is make it click the box of the correct one based on the value in my .csv file.  I have tried a bunch of different things with no success.  I always get invalid selector or cant find the element.
Here's the latest i have:

```
group2=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='checkbox'][value=cells[6]]").click()
```

The value I want from the csv is in the 7th column, I know I can use DictReader and have it read the column names which I will do once I get this working.

HELP?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable is inside the string so python doesn't recognize it as a variable. Try something like

```
group2=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='checkbox'][value=" + cells[6] + "]").click()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  I tried something similar to that but must have had the quotes and tick marks messed up.  Thanks!!